# What to put as "sender" for post_save receiver?

Tags: python, django

My `models.py` looks like this right now:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=Employee)
    def set_perms(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
        if created:
            restaurant = instance.restaurant
            assign_perm("change_user", instance, instance)
            assign_perm("view_restaurant", instance, restaurant)
```

I'm getting an error `NameError: name 'Employee' is not defined` which I'm not too surprised about. However, what should I put as the `sender` instead?

Note: I know it's best practice for signals to be in another file completely but I just want to get things working for now.

Comment: Why is the receiver inside the class of Employee? I think if you put it outside the class it will work fine.

Comment: You usually put all your receiver functions for an app in a file called `receivers.py`